# How to make a runnable where the run code is able to access a variable provided in the trigger

Tags: java, android, runnable

I have a class listening to a websocket and when a message is received, it should execute some code depending on the message type.
Throughout my application I want to be able to register more listeners.

I created the following MessageListener class:

```
static class MessageListener {
    private String triggerMessage;
    private Runnable runnable;

    MessageListener(String message, Runnable runnable) {
        this.triggerMessage = message;
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    private void trigger(String message) {
        if (message.equals(triggerMessage)) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    }
}
```

I add a listener like this:

```
ws.setListener(new IPDWebSocket.MessageListener("disconnect", new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Log.e("xx", "Received message: ");
        }
    }
  )
);
```

When a message is received it will trigger the listeners like this:

```
for (int nr=0; nr < listeners.size(); nr++) {
    listeners.get(nr).trigger(msg);
}
```

Now my problem is that in the Runnable I would like to be able to use the message variable. Something like this:

```
ws.setListener(new IPDWebSocket.MessageListener("disconnect", new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Log.e("xx", "Received message: " + message);
        }
    }
  )
);
```

But obviously the variable "message" isn't defined anywhere.
Any idea's on how to get this implemented? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Why don't you simply set it directly in the `run` method implementation? `Log.e("xx", "Received message: disconnect");`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but I'm actually looking to insert more variables. I changed it somewhat to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Runnable you can use your own `interface` to achieve this scenario,

Ex Create one interface inside your `MessageListener`

```
static class MessageListener {
    private String triggerMessage;
    private MessageTriggerListener runnable;

    public interface MessageTriggerListener {
        public void onMessageReceived(String message);
    }

    MessageListener(String message, MessageTriggerListener runnable) {
        this.triggerMessage = message;
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    private void trigger(String message) {
        if (message.equals(triggerMessage)) {
            runnable.onMessageReceived(message);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can implement the listener like this,

```
ws.setListener(new IPDWebSocket.MessageListener("disconnect", new MessageListener.MessageTriggerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(String message) {
                Log.e("xx", "Received message: " + message);
            }
        }
        )
);
```

Comment: Wow, that totally works, thanks a lot for helping me out! I have been struggling for hours to get this implemented!!! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could set the message directly in `run` method implementation.

```
ws.setListener(createListener("disconnect"));
ws.setListener(createListener("connect"));

private IPDWebSocket.MessageListener createListener(final String message) {
  return new IPDWebSocket.MessageListener(message, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Log.e("xx", "Received message: " + message);
        }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: I did try that but the runnable code is always the same. For each message received, I want to add different code to execute.